# Random In-App Content Purchases

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Can In-App purchases be random content? such as random 'items' or random 'accessories' or 'weapons', or other types of content?

I've read the guidelines and it does say you can't purchase a 'lottery ticket' but I'm not sure if this would be considered a lottery ticket?

Can anyone give me any further insight on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most games sell ingame currency for money. I've seen several games where you then can buy a "mystery box" for the ingame currency.

I think the reference to lottery is where you win something "outside" of your game, i.e. stuffs sent to you or real money etc.